# Create a new package based on “default” package’s “default” theme

Tags: theme, frontend, package, certification

I'm studying to get Magento FE certification and I've found some demo questions like this:

> You want to create a new “screendesign” package based on the “default”
>   package’s “default” theme. Which ONE of the following steps do you
>   have to take?
>
> A. Copy app/design/base to app/design/screendesign
>
> B. Create an empty folder app/design/frontend/screendesign and copy
>   app/design/frontend/default/default into it
>
> C. Create skin/frontend/screendesign, then copy the CSS and images
>   folders and their files from /skin/frontend/default/default/ to
>   skin/frontend/screendesign/default
>
> D. Inside app/design/frontend and skin/frontend, copy the folder
>   “default” to the folder “custom”; then rename custom/default to
>   custom/screendesign in both places
>
> E. Create app/design/frontend/default/screendesign

The answer suggested is C, but I don't agree and I think is B because if you don't create at least the package folder, you'll get error when setting the package (folder not found). Am I wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is definitely C.

If you choose B then that says:

> B. Create an empty folder app/design/frontend/screendesign and copy app/design/frontend/default/default into it

That means you'd have `app/design/frontend/screendesign/template`  and  `app/design/frontend/screendesign/layout`.

The files would be in the wrong location.

What you would want is:

`app/design/frontend/screendesign/default/template` and `app/design/frontend/screendesign/default/layout`.

Comment: Remember, the question says which "one" of the following steps.  It doesn't specify that you're creating the whole package/theme with any of these options.

Comment: If you do  "cp -r default/default screendesign/" the folder structure will be correct. The error could happen if you do " cp -r default/default/ screendesign/". However I've understood your point of view. thanks

Comment: @seanbreeden : I am confused with your answer. What I understood from option B is, copy the `default` folder to `screendesign` folder. That means, it will give you a structure like `screendesign/default` and thus path become correct.

Comment: It doesn't say "copy the `default` folder to screendesign".  It says to copy `default/default` to it.  The contents of default/default/* would be copied to app/design/frontend/screendesign/.  Had the answer stated: `Create an empty folder app/design/frontend/screendesign/default and copy app/design/frontend/default/default into it` then that would be correct.

Comment: I think that is an unclear question because "default/default" is different from "default/default/", a least in the *nix environment. I hope to not find a similar question when I will take the exam!

Comment: They carefully plan these questions.  I found the MCD test to be very fair but very difficult at the same time (even though I failed it on the first attempt :) ). I haven't taken the front-end test yet but the folks that created the MCD did a good job.